# Xcom_pull() got an unexpected keyword argument 'task_id'

Tags: airflow, python-3.11

I'm learning Apache Airflow from course of Marc Lamberti, I stumbled on a problem, in my task "process_user"

```
def _process_user(ti):
    user = ti.xcom_pull(task_id = "extract_user")
    user = user['results'][0]
    processed_user =  json_normalize({
        'first_name': user['name']['first'],
        'last_name': user['name']['last'],
        'country': user['location']['country'],
        'username': user['login']['username'],
        'password': user['login']['password'],
        'email': user['email']})
    processed_user.to_csv('/tmp/processed_user.csv', index=None, header=False)

...

with DAG(dag_id='user_processing',
        start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
        schedule_interval='@daily',
        catchup=False) as dag:

    ...

    extract_user = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='extract_user',
        http_conn_id='user_api',
        endpoint='api/',
        method='GET',
        response_filter = lambda response: 
        json.loads(response.text),
        log_response = True
    )

    process_user = PythonOperator(
        task_id='process_user',
        python_callable = _process_user
    )

    ...
```

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: xcom_pull() got an unexpected keyword argument 'task_id'
```

where did I do wrong ?

I found solution:

I used this code:

```
def _process_user(**kwargs):
    user = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids="extract_user")
```

Comment: task_ids instead if task_id. Add "s"

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is `task_ids` thus it should be

```
user = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids = "extract_user")
```

See [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/cede385e938d4645fdbdfabd6c92c02fbfb95628/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L2493) parameters for this function.